# How was a user able to enforce a unique value for a choice column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-addin, column, site-column

I have a document library with a choice column with possible values. In library settings, I have selected 'No' for both 'Enforce unique values:' and 'Allow 'Fill-in' choices:' [image: Document Type Column Settings]

A user was still able to enforce a unique value. I have never seen this happening before.

StandardPortrait2 is the unique value and it's not the possible choice for Document Type column. [image: enforced unique value]

Any idea how is that even possible?

Comment: Please share What happen in the new form ?

Comment: Did someone change the column definition after documents were added? Can anything upload files to the library besides the SharePoint UI? (Custom code?)

Comment: Thank you. I didn't change the column definition. I am the only one who has Full Control. Everyone else has contributor access.No custom code either. It's an OOTB document library with one column named 'Document Type' with possible choices. Allow Fill In Choices = No. Enforce Unique Values = No.

Answer (score 0):

The document `StandardPortrait2` was added due to a number of reasons at that time.

1. The field setting `Allow 'Fill-in' choices` was set to yes.
2. `StandardPortrait2` was added in the allowed values.
3. The user who added the document might have permissions to modify the field.
4. Via some code or workflow

Comment: Thank you.  1. Allow Fill-In Choices is set to No since the document library was created very first time. 3. The user has contributor access. 4. The user has contributor access. No one besides me have full control and I haven't changed anything.

Comment: There is a `Status Reports` document type as well that is not in the allowable list. Is is also something strange in addition to the `StandardPortrait2`?